# Dar opción a que el programa corra tantas veces como se le indique

Tags: c

Éste es mi programa, y añadí el char y el primer ciclo do-while (el general) es el que no me sirve.

Y también necesito saber como puedo hacer la validación de datos desde mi pseudocódigo, pues según yo es igual con un ciclo do-while, pero no me corre tampoco

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    float menor=INT_MAX, num;
    char resp;

    do 
    { 
        do 
        {
            printf("Dame un numero positivo (-1 para terminar): \n");
            scanf("%f", &num);
            if((num!=-1)&&(num<menor))
                menor=num;
        } while (num != -1);

        printf("El numero mas chico es: %.1f\n", menor);
        printf("\nsi quieres continuar en el programa? (si=s)(no=n)\n");
        scanf("%c", &resp);
    } while ((resp == 's')||(resp != 'n'));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando lees caracteres sueltos tienes que tener cuidado porque esta lectura, a diferencia de otras, no descarta los saltos de línea.

Vamos a verlo con un ejemplo.

Cuando el programa te pide un número, supongamos que introduces el -1. El buffer de entrada tendrá 4 caracteres:

```
0x000 0x001 0x002 0x003
    -     1    \n [EOF]
```

La lectura del `scanf` leerá el número, dejando el resto en el buffer de entrada:

```
0x000 0x001
   \n [EOF]
```

Ahora el programa te pide que indiques si quieres continuar o no. La llamada a `scanf` ve que hay caracteres que puede leer (el salto de línea) y eso es justamente lo que va a almacenar en `resp`.

Para descartar esos saltos de línea basta con modificar ligeramente la lectura:

```
scanf(" %c", &resp);
//     ^ espacio en blanco
```

Con esto el problema que comentas ya está solucionado. Sin embargo hay un par de detalles a corregir en tu aplicación:

1. Para manejar enteros, usa `int`, no `float`:

   ```
    int menor=INT_MAX, num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
   ```

   O, si lo que vas a hacer es manejar números con decimales, inicializa correctamente la variable:

   ```
    float menor=FLT_MAX;
   ```

   Cada tipo de variable admite un rango de valores diferente. Metiendo valores altos, tu programa fallaría irremediablemente.
2. La condición del segundo `while` es redundante. Si yo te digo:

   > Elije el color que quieras, pero tendrás que elegir otro mientras el color sea rojo o no sea negro

   El mensaje es un poco extraño, ¿no crees? ¿No quedaría más claro así?

   > Elije el color que quieras, pero tendrás que elegir otro mientras no sea negro

   Hemos dicho exactamente lo mismo, solo que en el primer caso hemos añadido una condición totalmente innecesaria. Eso mismo le está pasando a tu `while`.

   ```
    while(resp != 'n');
   ```

   Así queda más claro, ¿no crees? Otra cosa es que decidas añadir una validación para forzar al usuario a introducir un valor válido, es decir, que el programa repita la pregunta mientras no se conteste correctamente:

   ```
        printf("El numero mas chico es: %.1f\n", menor);

        do
        {
            printf("\nsi quieres continuar en el programa? (si=s)(no=n)\n");
            scanf("%c", &resp);
        } while(resp!='s' && resp!='n'); 
    } while (resp != 'n');
   ```